# Include AJAX parameter and reload datatable

Tags: datatables

I have a datatable (I am using Jquery Datatable 1.10) that uses an AJAX data source, which accepts a parameter, as below:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    ajax: {
        url: "http://example.com/end/point",
        data: {"id": "12345"}
} );
```

This works really well.

I have a chart on the page, which when clicked must reload the datatable with the `"id"` from the chart element value.

Ideally, i'd like to use something similar to this but with the new `"id"` parameter included.

```
    table.ajax.url( "http://example.com/end/point").load();
```

Is there anyway to use the API to reload the data based on a new `"id"` parameter?

(I'd prefer not to chain the id onto the URL as a string as it feels clumsy)

Answer (score 0):

If the id value is assigned from a selector:

```
data: {"id": $("#chartelementid").val()}
```

Then you can call fnDraw() in the click event and the new chart element id will be used when reloading the data:

```
table.fnDraw();
```